# Strangest JS ternary statement I've ever seen

Tags: javascript

So i'm working on this project, which has code someone else wrote, and I found this javascript ternary operation to assign a variable. They aren't available for me to ask about it. I understand the first half, but ...

`variable = statement ? option1 : option2 ? option2 : option1`

it would be simple for me if it was just

`variable = statement ? option1 : option2`

but the second half of the statement is just baffling to me. Can someone please explain what is happening here?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem" - An opinion is not a specific problem

Answer (score 1):

```
variable = statement ? option1 : option2 ? option2 : option1
```

is, spaced out:

```
variable = statement
  ? option1
  : option2
    ? option2
    : option1
```

If statement, option1.

Otherwise, if option2, option2.

Otherwise, option1.

Another way of doing it is:

```
if (statement) {
  variable = option1;
} else if (option2) {
  variable = option2;
} else {
  variable = option1;
}
```

A clearer way of implementing the same logic would be:

```
if (!statement && option2) {
  variable = option2;
} else {
  variable = option1;
}
```

or

```
variable = (!statement && option2)
  ? option2
  : option1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the same.
`variable = statement ? option1 : option2 ? option2 : option1`
would be the equivalent of -

```js
if (statement) {
   variable = option1;
} else {
   if (option2) {
      variable = option2;
   } else {
      variable = option1;
   }
}
```

Where as
`variable = statement ? option1 : option2`
would be equivalent to -

```js
if (statement) {
   variable = option1;
} else {
   variable = option2;
}
```

As can be more clearly seen here, in the second example, if `statement` is `false`, variable will always be equal to `option2`.
But in the first example, it can still be equal to `option1` in some cases.